how can i update my invoice after POSTing to Xero, when I let Xero generate the Invoice Nr and Id
I would like to send 2 very basic invoices to xero.
Let xero create the Invoice Nr, and InvoiceId, then return that so i can update it on our side.
After sending our IDE creates a NEW Root.
Is there any way to send some kind of GUID with the invoice, so i can match and update the info later?
{ "Invoices": [ { "Type": "ACCREC", "Contact": { "ContactID": "XYZ" }, "Status": "AUTHORISED", "LineItems": [ { "Description": "16 Jul 2024 transport ", "Quantity": "28", "UnitAmount": "190", "LineAmount": "5351.", "AccountCode": "200" } ] }, { "Type": "ACCREC", "Contact": { "ContactID": "ABC" }, "Status": "AUTHORISED", "LineItems": [ { "Description": "16 Jul 2024 transport TCI U 316377 8123", "Quantity": "30.005", "UnitAmount": "190", "LineAmount": "5700.95", "AccountCode": "200" } ] } ] }
I have tried using client + amount, but this is not a great way of solving this.

In order to send a unique identifier to Xero besides using the ReferenceId, invoiceId or InvoiceNr the URL field can be used if the URL field is not already used for something else.

For ACCREC invoices you can include an identifier in the Reference field, as described here.

I would like Xero to generate the Reference, and if I add one, then Xero don't generate one.
